# How can you take a panorama picture using Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How to take a panorama picture using Ionic ? i tried using the camera plugin on ionic but no luck. it just take a simple picture.

Answer (score 0):

Extra Camera features such as panorama mode (with multiple images blending etc) are not yet exposed by platforms APIs unfortunately. You can not achieve it in Ionic since current plugins do not have those functions.